# Create a chart populated with all the data calculated for each value in a dropdown in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a sheet in excel that calculates a specific value for each option from a list of dropdowns.

I now want to create a chart that compares the calculated value for each dropdown option.

Is there a way to populate a table or a chart with all of the calculations for each drop-down option in Excel? Or would I have to separate the dropdown options into separate lists and get each value that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may be workarounds, but Excel charts were designed to plot data from worksheets. Put the dropdown options in a sheet and the calculations next to those options, then insert the chart you need.